# Is magic considered to be physical, astral, or other?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic

This may seem like a silly question, but it is being asked in isolation for clarity.

Is magic a physical force, an astral force, or considered its own separate attribute of magical?

The subtext of this question involves *wall of force* and the exclusion principle in that it doesn't state "magic" as something it stops.

Comment: **Historical note:** Second edition's Planescape setting defined very explicitly which spells required a connection to the Astral Plane, which used the Ethereal Plane, and so on. The vast majority of spells and magic items would function without significant change regardless of which plane the magic user was on, but the exceptions were rather interesting. *Identify* only worked on planes connected to the Astral and so would not work if cast on one of the inner planes, for example.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what this question means. What is a “physical force” or “astral force” in this context? I doubt it has much to do with older editions’ planar interactions in spells, at least that doesn’t seem like the context this is coming from to me.

Comment: Hi @Play Patrice, it does not help your question's clarity that you ask it in isolation. We will be much better able to help you if, on the contrary, you provide us with as much context about where and why that question arises as you can, because then we can target what kind of answer you are looking for, and vote on answers according to whether they are helpful in that context or not.

Comment: I feel the question is simplistic enough to stand on it's own.   The reason it needs to stand in isolation is due to popular opinion overriding context.  If I mention the other context people will argue the context and not the issue at hand.  Which is why It is stated in isolation.   It comes down to Magic is X - What is x?

Comment: Nobody knows what X is. That's what *makes* it magic. If we knew what X was, we would be talking about science.

Comment: Hi @PlayPatrice, I feel your pain.  I've struggled myself to shake the rpg.se tree to produce the knowledge that I was sure was hanging there like ripe fruit just out of my grasp.  However, I just don't see how this question is answerable as is.  There are ample other questions on the nature of magic and sections within the rules.  Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Now that you have accepted an answer, I guess I understand what you wanted to know, but I still don’t know what an “astral force” is or what that means. I’m honestly interested in that, though, so clarifying your question is *still* a good idea even if you are satisfied with the answer you’ve received.

Comment: @KRyan Excellent point - and always good to remember that the Questions here are both for the person who asked them and others who may have the same question later. Clarifying so a question can be reopened (especially if there's answer that 's working for you) improves the whole community.

Comment: The answer to you question is in the Players Handbook.  Do you own a copy?

Comment: Based on the user's other questions, I believe this question is actually about gathering rules support for a loophole that allows magic to pass through a _wall of force_; it blocks "physically" moving through it and ethereal travel (but not astral travel). The actual question of whether magic can bypass a _wall of force_ has already been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Magic is its own thing.

According to the D&D 5th edition *Player's Handbook*, p. 201 (Ch. 10, ["Spellcasting"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting)):

> Magic permeates the worlds of D&D and most often appears in the form of a spell. [...] A spell is a discrete magical effect, a single shaping of the magical energies that suffuse the multiverse into a specific, limited expression. In casting a spell, a character carefully plucks at the invisible strands of raw magic suffusing the world [...]

- Magical is not physical, per se, although it can be used to create
  physical effects, it's **magical energies that suffuse the
  multiverse**.
- It's not "astral", although some spells do affect the Astral Plane.
  *Dungeon Master's Guide* p. 46-48 describes the Astral Plane, and it
  isn't described as the source of magic, or made of magic, at any
  point. The DM is, of course, free to invent their own campaign
  setting where this is the case.

Comment: *Raw magic is the stuff of creation, the mute and mindless will of existence, permeating every bit of matter and present in every manifestation of energy throughout the multiverse*  I recommend you add that bit to your "magic is its own thing" as it comes from the text box on page 205, PHB.  I think it would help strengthen the point you are making.